# Preset / Native Elements in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little trouble understanding CSS and have a question:

If I have a preset/native element to CSS e.g. `fieldset` and add the class `.scheduler-border` so it looks like this: `fieldset.scheduler-border` it works great.

But when I create a custom element, e.g. `fieldset2` and apply the same element onto my custom element e.g. `fieldset2.scheduler-border` I don't get the desired result.

Could someone explain to me the reason of this?

Comment: What do you mean by create a custom element?

Answer (score 0):

Its because `<fieldset>` is a tag. If you want to identify two different fieldsets use an id or another class for example:

`<fieldset id="2">` or `<fieldset class="2">` that way in your css you can call `#2{your changes here for id2}` or  `.2{your changes here for class2}` but you cannot change the `<tag>` values

Comment: So the html would look like <fieldset class="2">

And the CSS:

fieldset2 {
/*Content*/
}

Would that work?

Comment: I just used `class="2"` as an example but you would be better off calling it something relevant like  `<fieldset class="box-border">` so when you refer back to your css it would say `.box-border{/*content*/} `

Comment: Okay that's great, can I also do this <fieldset class="2" id="2"> as well?

Comment: @Cierce - you should read up on the basics of CSS and HTML. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started

Comment: yes, your css then would look like `#2.2{/*content*/}`

Comment: I did look around the manual and couldn't find anything that I understood, but you've cleared up my question and I very much appreciate that; I think I'll take another read of it now as well. I would up vote but can't, sorry bud.

Comment: This way you can uniquely Identify each field set. example `<fieldset class="2" id="1">` and `<fieldset class="2" id="2">` then in your css have `#1.2</*content*/>` and `#2.2</*content*/>` so both share the same class properties while whatever you have for the ids would be unique

Comment: @Cierce could you mark my answer as correct, because I will get down voted for not using best practices, but it is a lot easier to explain to someone new like I did.